# How many years have passed between season 5 and 6 of The Americans

Tags: the-americans

Just started to get caught up on the current season of "The Americans".  There is a time jump from the end of season 5 to the start of season 6 and i'm attempting to figure out the amount of time that has actually passed.

if you look at Henry in school, it mentions that he is in his Junior year at the private school he wanted to go to at the end of season 5, so that seems to indicate 3 years.

But the Paige story line seems to (for some reason to me) seem to imply that only maybe 2 years has passed.

and the Kimmy storyline (maybe he was older than I was remembering) seems to indicate maybe as much as 4 years.   So i'm curious if anyone else has figure out or found reference to the exact amount of time that has passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Americans_(season_5))

Season 5 runs between:

> February 1984 and August 1984, shown by the reference to the TV broadcasts of the 1984 Winter Olympics in episode 1 and the coverage of Ronald Reagan's "We begin bombing in five minutes" joke in episode 13.

Whereas [**Season 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Americans_(season_6))...

> The events of the sixth season begin in late September 1987, three years after the conclusion of season five.

From Episode 1 of that season..

> Elizabeth is exhausted and resentful from handling a full KGB case load nine weeks before the Reagan-Gorbachev summit...

...which was held December 8–10 1987

So **3 years would be correct.**

Comment: awesome. that clears up a few things for me